# Exception in liferay after setting tomcat host

Tags: tomcat, liferay, host

My portal is working properly. I am trying to set the alias for a domain name and making the configuration in tomcat's server.xml

```
<Host name="mydomain.gr" appBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/vulnerable"
unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
      <Alias>mydomain.gr</Alias>
<Context  path=""   docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/vulnerable"  swallowOutput="true" crossContext="true"></Context>
</Host>
```

After restarting tomcat I get the following exception

```
20:38:23,251 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PortalBeanLocatorUtil:89] BeanLocator is null
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1365)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portlet.blogs.service.BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.getService(BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.java:837)
    at com.liferay.portlet.blogs.service.BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.checkEntries(BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.java:389)
    at com.liferay.portlet.blogs.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener.doReceive(CheckEntryMessageListener.java:28)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy297.receive(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.messaging.SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.receive(SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.java:76)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20:38:23,257 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][ParallelDestination:94] Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=null, values={JOB_NAME=com.liferay.portlet.blogs.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, EXCEPTIONS_MAX_SIZE=0, GROUP_NAME=com.liferay.portlet.blogs.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, DESTINATION_NAME=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, JOB_STATE=com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.JobState@36915814, companyId=0, MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME=com.liferay.portlet.blogs.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, RECEIVER_KEY=com.liferay.portlet.blogs.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener.com.liferay.portlet.blogs.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, MESSAGE_LISTENER_UUID=d690c9f1-b757-4482-a22c-d95a99f9715a}}
com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has not been set
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy297.receive(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.messaging.SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.receive(SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.java:76)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has not been set
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.java:82)
    at com.liferay.portlet.blogs.service.BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.getService(BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.java:837)
    at com.liferay.portlet.blogs.service.BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.checkEntries(BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.java:389)
    at com.liferay.portlet.blogs.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener.doReceive(CheckEntryMessageListener.java:28)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:26)
    ... 12 more
20:38:32,357 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-2][ParallelDestination:94] Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=null, values={JOB_NAME=com.liferay.portal.deploy.messaging.RequiredPluginsMessageListener, EXCEPTIONS_MAX_SIZE=0, GROUP_NAME=com.liferay.portal.deploy.messaging.RequiredPluginsMessageListener, DESTINATION_NAME=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, JOB_STATE=com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.JobState@73bb4449, companyId=0, MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME=com.liferay.portal.deploy.messaging.RequiredPluginsMessageListener, RECEIVER_KEY=com.liferay.portal.deploy.messaging.RequiredPluginsMessageListener.com.liferay.portal.deploy.messaging.RequiredPluginsMessageListener, MESSAGE_LISTENER_UUID=68e67fa7-8dd2-456a-b942-5087df10ec7c}}
com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy297.receive(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.messaging.SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.receive(SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.java:76)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.DeployManagerUtil.getLevelsRequiredDeploymentContexts(DeployManagerUtil.java:60)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.messaging.RequiredPluginsMessageListener.doReceive(RequiredPluginsMessageListener.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:26)
    ... 12 more
20:38:40,946 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][ContextLoader:94] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPool' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPortalCacheManager' while setting bean property 'portalCacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPortalCacheManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' of type [com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPortalCacheManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' of type [com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:441)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:982)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:878)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService.init(ManagementService.java:245)
    at com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager.afterPropertiesSet(EhcachePortalCacheManager.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.jmx.MBeanRegistry.register(MBeanRegistry.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.jmx.RegistryAwareMBeanServer.registerMBean(RegistryAwareMBeanServer.java:307)
    at net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService.registerCacheManager(ManagementService.java:264)
    at net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService.init(ManagementService.java:232)
    ... 52 more
Jan 07, 2015 8:38:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPool' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPortalCacheManager' while setting bean property 'portalCacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPortalCacheManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' of type [com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPortalCacheManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' of type [com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:441)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:982)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:878)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#4796e6c0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService.init(ManagementService.java:245)
    at com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager.afterPropertiesSet(EhcachePortalCacheManager.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=liferay-multi-vm-clustered
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.jmx.MBeanRegistry.register(MBeanRegistry.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.jmx.RegistryAwareMBeanServer.registerMBean(RegistryAwareMBeanServer.java:307)
    at net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService.registerCacheManager(ManagementService.java:264)
    at net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService.init(ManagementService.java:232)
    ... 52 more
```

If I remove the server.xml lines everything gets back to normal. What do I miss? I am using tomcat 7.0.55 and liferay 6.2

**EDIT
I noticed that the stacktrace with the above exception starts after a second attempt to connect hibernate. The first time with the new host and the second with localhost

so the part that gets repeated is

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext 214:13:15,432 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:119] Determine dialect for MySQL 5 314:13:15,546 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] DialectDetector:119] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

set virtual hosts in Liferay via Control Panel for a site (not in server.xml)